# Inserting blank rows between records and outputting to CSV

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, replace

I need to modify strings in two CSV files. I am using Windows XP.

The file names are **pi_jobs.csv** and **pi_offices.csv**.

I require two blank spaces between each record, and then two blank rows after the last record.

The files are generated by an Access-based application, and I’ve been able to create the blank rows in the output via the SQL statement (basically, the last field in the query concatenates two sets of Chr(10) and Chr(13) characters, giving me two line feeds and two carriage returns).

However, when I output the files to CSV it includes those carriage returns and line feeds as a separate field in the record, and thus puts a comma before the field, and quotes around the field.

I've provided an example below. Note gap between the first and second record. There is a comma and quotation mark at the end of the first record, and a closing quotation mark before the start of the second record:

> “An accredited Medical Assisting program where eligible to receive either AAMA or AMT certification; High School Diploma or GED required; Minimum of three years work experience in a medical or related business office; Working knowledge of phlebotomy and administering injections.  Desired:  Associates Degree."," 
>  
>   
>  
>   
>  
>   " 
>  
>   "TBP20113105-82792","chicago-edgewater","9999999","TBP Medical Assistant"

I've been very careful with my page formatting here - that is exactly how the line spacing looks. There are three line gaps in that spacing. It should, however, look like this:

> “An accredited Medical Assisting program where eligible to receive either AAMA or AMT certification; High School Diploma or GED required; Minimum of three years work experience in a medical or related business office; Working knowledge of phlebotomy and administering injections.  Desired:  Associates Degree."
>   
>  
>   
>   "TBP20113105-82792","chicago-edgewater","9999999","TBP Medical Assistant"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure Access solution.

Step 1: **Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime library in your database**

[image]

Step 2: **Create a function that will open the table/query and read the records line-by-line and outputs to .csv file**

```
Function OutputToCsv()
Dim fs As FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim rs As Recordset

On Error GoTo lberr

'use this if you query a single table
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Column1, Column2, Column3 From NewTable")

'use this if your query DOES NOT have any parameters
'Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Column1, Column2, Column3 From NewQuery")

'use this if you use query WITH parameter(s)
'Dim qdf As QueryDef
'Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("NewQuery")
'qdf.Parameters("Parameter1") = "" 'set the value for the parameter(s)
'Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset

If (rs.RecordCount = 0) Then Exit Function

Set fs = New FileSystemObject
Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\NewFile.csv", True, False) 'this will overwrite the file each time

rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF
    'Chr(34) is a quotation mark "
    ts.WriteLine (Chr(34) & rs("Column1") & Chr(34)) 'format your record output
    'ts.WriteLine (Chr(34) & rs("Column1") & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & rs("Column2") & Chr(34)) 'in case you need to output more than one column
    ts.WriteBlankLines (2) 'Add as many empty lines as you need
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

ts.Close

MsgBox "Success!"

Exit Function
lberr:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Function
```

And, this is how your output file should look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - is there any way in your statement to specify the query to be run? In your example, you have the line: Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Column1, Column2, Column3 From NewTable")   but I've tried including (and modifying) my query SQL in that line, but I'm getting compile errors. If it helps at all, the query name is "aje-job-output-query".  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, query can be used as well. I am going to edit my post to include that

Comment: How is using the File System Object a "pure Access solution", particularly when VBA has file I/O functions that can do this without any additional references?